# How to prevent the keyboard from opening automatically in my Ionic2 App?

Tags: ionic2

I am developing a Mobile App using the Ionic2-Framework along with Angular2.
In a section of my app, I have several `<ion-slides>` with `<ion-item><ion-input ...></ion-input></ion-item>` on the slides.

When changing the slide, the keyboard opens up without actively touching one of the input-fields. So far, I could only test it on iOS, but I found out that it only happens for `type="tel"`-inputs

Is there a way to prevent the app from doing this, as I would like the users to choose the time to input by themselves.

The code of my page looks like that:
(I excluded some parts for readability)

```
<ion-header>
  <ion-navbar>
    <button ion-button icon-only menuToggle [hidden]="showBackButton">
      <ion-icon color="primary" name="menu"></ion-icon>
    </button>
    <button color="light" ion-button icon-only [hidden]="!showBackButton" (click)="goToPreviousSlide()">
      <ion-icon color="primary" name="arrow-back"></ion-icon>
    </button>
    <ion-title>Title</ion-title>
  </ion-navbar>
</ion-header>

<ion-content padding>

  <ion-slides (ionSlideDidChange)="updateShowBackButton()">

    <!-- Some more slides... -->

    <ion-slide style="background-color: white" padding>
      <h2 class="slide-title">Hello {{person.name}}!</h2>
      <p>Now I need this and that information:/p>

      <ion-item>
        <ion-label>Day</ion-label>
        <ion-input type="tel" fixed [(ngModel)]="person.day"></ion-input>
      </ion-item>
      <ion-item>
        <ion-label>Month</ion-label>
        <ion-input type="tel" fixed [(ngModel)]="person.month"></ion-input>
      </ion-item>
      <ion-item>
        <ion-label>Year</ion-label>
        <ion-input type="tel" fixed [(ngModel)]="person.year"></ion-input>
      </ion-item>

      <ion-item-divider></ion-item-divider>

      <ion-item>
        <ion-label>Height (cm)</ion-label>
        <ion-input type="tel" fixed [(ngModel)]="person.height"></ion-input>
      </ion-item>
      <ion-item>
        <ion-label>Weight: (kg)</ion-label>
        <ion-input type="tel" fixed [(ngModel)]="person.weight"></ion-input>

      </ion-item>

      <button ion-button block (click)="goToNextSlide()">Next</button>

    </ion-slide>

    <!-- Some more slides... -->

  </ion-slides>

</ion-content>
```

If you need futher information, please let me know! I am appreciating any hints! :)

Comment: Can you please post the page where you have the `ion-slide?

Comment: @GabrielWabiz I added the code of my page!